# Sequelize queryInterface bulkDelete does not reset id sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js, bulk-delete

I use `pg_dump` to make a copy of the database, `copy1.sql`.

I run an up migration to create a new instance

```
up: asyn (queryInterface) => {
  return await queryInterface.bulkInsert('keys', [{ clientKey: 'key123' }]);
}
```

I run a down migration to delete the instance

```
down: async (queryInterface) => {
  return await queryInterface.bulkDelete('keys', { clientKey: ['key123'] });
}
```

I do another `pg_dump` of the database, `copy2.sql`. I compare the first copy of the database with the second copy of the database to show that the down migration worked properly by running a bash script
`diff "copy1.sql" "copy2.sql"`

The difference is

```
-SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.keys_id_seq', 6, true);
+SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.keys_id_seq', 7, true);
```

This makes my test fail because the copies of both databases are not identical due to this difference. Even though I deleted that key, it's saying the next id sequence is going to start at 8 instead of 7 according to this [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-sequence.html). The table rows that currently exists are 1 through 6. Is there a way to delete the instance so that the sequence will start at 7 instead of 8? Meaning both copies of the database should have

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('public.keys_id_seq', 6, true);
```

Are there options I can include? Maybe something like

```
down: async (queryInterface) => {
  return await queryInterface.bulkDelete('keys', { clientKey: ['key123'] }, { resetIdSequence: true });
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option. You should manually set a sequence to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset sequence using the `truncate table` command. `Truncate table` command erases all table data. For example:

```
truncate table table_name restart identity;
```

Second way manual resetting using `setval`. Example:

```
select setval('your_table_id_seq', 1, false);
```

If you don't delete all table data, then recommended set sequence value to the maximum id of records. Example:

```
select setval('your_table_id_seq', COALESCE((select max(id)+1 from your_table), 1), false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I don't want to delete the whole table. And was looking for a way to perform the delete or pg_dump so that I wouldn't manually have to reset `setval`. Looks like there's no solution to this :(

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be too late for you but I had the same problem and resolved it by adding `{restartIdentity: true}` on my migration file, like this (example of one of my tables):

```js
async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('card', {restartIdentity: true});
  }
```

To be sure it works I tried several "turns" with those commands on the terminal :

- `npx sequelize db:migrate`, `npx sequelize db:seed:all` : everything is on place :)
- `npx sequelize db:migrate:undo:all` : no tables, good!
- `npx sequelize db:migrate`, `npx sequelize db:seed:all` : everything is good, foreign keys are still the good ones, great !

So for your code you could try this :

```js
down: async (queryInterface) => {
  return await queryInterface.bulkDelete('keys', { clientKey: ['key123'] }, {restartIdentity: true});
}
```

Hope this helps ;)